# Fourth Hat of Antique Hatrack Collection

Tags: west-of-loathing

In the credits sequence for :

> As for you? After your adventure you settled in Frisco and bought a
>   very long, very narrow house.
>   You filled it with souvenirs of your
>   exploits, and started an antique hatrack collection.

Which hat belongs on the fourth hatrack ?

[image: Hatrack, missing 4th]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [West of Loathing Wiki article on the hatrack](https://westofloathing.gamepedia.com/Antique_hatrack_collection) provides some insight as to what it could be; it seems the hats match the order yours are in.

By process of elimination I believe the missing hat to be the **'really nice cowboy hat'** which is found in the Temporal Nexus at the West Pole.

For reference, here is the hat list (information from the article); they must be in your inventory at the end of the game for them to appear in the credits sequence:

1. **four-gallon hat**, **barely-enchanted hat**, or **floppy derby** - picked up at Boring Springs, dependent on the player's class
2. **bear hat**, **cat hat**, or **owl hat** - a gift from Rufus after the first couple of postcards, if you picked a name at character creation by shooting the stuffed bear, cat, or owl figure
3. **fake Pope hat** - acquired from Saint Pope in the Old Mission catacombs
4. **really nice cowboy hat** - found in the Temporal Nexus at the West Pole
5. **prototype Stetson** - in the office at the Old Millinery, in a locked safe behind the locked door
6. **turnip crown** - the dusty turnip from Boring Springs, plated at The Silver Plater for 5000 meat (normal) or 20000 (hard mode)
7. **gold tooth crown** - made by the bone-obsessed hippy in Fort of Darkness from 23 gold teeth
8. **El Vibrato crown** - reward for activating the El Vibrato "Roberto Containment" machine in Deepest Delve Mine
9. **yeast-covered hat** - lying on the floor in Ol' Schmaltz Brewery
10. **strange head sack** - for trading an old patrol cap to the second hippy at Lazy A-Dude Ranch
11. **spittoon hat** - from the spittoon in Clooncy's Bar in Frisco

Comment: Excellent, thank you. At the time that I had asked, no such resource existed that I could find.